# How is FileInputStream used in Java

Tags: java, io, fileinputstream

I am trying to understand the following piece of code from Oreilly's Java IO. It is supposed to read from a file and write it to the console:

```
try {
  FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("README.TXT"); 
  int n;     
  while ((n = fis.available()) > 0) {
    byte[] b = new byte[n];
    int result = fis.read(b);
    if (result == -1) break;
    String s = new String(b);
    System.out.print(s); 
  } // End while
} // End try
catch (IOException e) {System.err.println(e);}
System.out.println();
```

My question is:

The `available` method will find the maximum length available at once, then the `read` method can be invoked to print it out. That should be done within one call, why is the author doing it in a `while` loop, checking for the availability continuously?

Comment: This is not an answer to your question, but I just want you to be aware that in general your file reading code doesn't have to be this low level.  Check out the [Apache Commons IOUtils](http://commons.apache.org/io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.html) for some higher level methods when you're ready to use them.

Comment: Okay, I will go through them also...

Answer (score 5):

From the [javadoc of available()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/FileInputStream.html#available%28%29) :

> Returns an estimate of the number of remaining bytes that can be read
>   (or skipped over) from this input stream without blocking by the next
>   invocation of a method for this input stream. The next invocation
>   might be the same thread or another thread. A single read or skip of
>   this many bytes will not block, but may read or skip fewer bytes.

The stream may block until you read part of it. So you must read only what is available each time. After a call to `read`, the stream will be unblocked.

So there are still available bytes at next iteration, except when the end of file is reached. At this points `result` is -1 as stated by [the javadoc of read()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/FileInputStream.html#read%28byte%5B%5D%29) :

> Returns
>
> the total number of bytes read into the buffer, or -1 if there is no
>   more data because the end of the file has been reached.

Note that very often you don't read all what is available, because you want to use reasonably sized buffers (and reuse them). In such a case `n` would be `Math.min(BUFFER_SIZE, fix.available())`.

Comment: How does it avoid loading the whole file? The first call to `available` should return the number of bytes corresponding to the entire file content, no?

Comment: Can you please explain in a bit more detail this statement: **The stream may block until you read part of it. So you must read only what is available each time. After a call to read, the stream will be unblocked.

So there are still available bytes at next iteration, except when the end of file is reached (at this points result is -1).**?

Comment: Any reading operation copying bytes into a byte array has to be limited. An inputstream can even be infinite, which isn't the case for the memory of your computer.

Comment: So, is it because of something like this: the `available` method checks for the bytes available for reading. That need not be the total number of bytes that can be read from the stream, for some other thread might be blocking a subsequent portion of it. So the `while` loop starts with reading the available number of bytes. If no other thread is blocking the stream, that will be the total number of bytes that can be read, and the loop will end. Else, it will read the available bytes, hoping that at the start of next iteration, the blocked part will be unblocked..If so, continue like that.

Comment: The fact that another thread might be reading isn't the only reason why a stream might not be entirely available. The notions of file and stream are generic enough : a stream might be infinitely written while you're reading it.

Comment: Okay, whatever be the reason, is that the explanation? Else, what am I missing?

Comment: There could be all kind of underlying reasons why a stream only has a set number of bytes available to read at a time. A disk device could be seeking across cluster for the next available data having already fulfilled part of the request. A device could be waiting on an interrupt from the OS prior to reading the next batch of data, the OS might be servicing other IO requests after having delivered a portion of the data ... the list goes on. Bottom line is, you are not guaranteed to be able to read your entire file in one call, and you need to be prepared to handle that in your code.